# Error Cloning/pushing git organizational repository in dbeaver(git integration)

Tags: github, egit, dbeaver

I am getting an error when trying to clone an organization git repository in dbeaver.
I am guessing its an authentication issue or something.
Any insights appreciated.

Note:

- My credentials are correct.
- I am using https protocol.
- I am able to clone/push using git desktop without error.
- My user account has admin role to this repository.
- I am able to clone/push a non organizational repository in dbeaver.

ERROR: " ... git-upload-pack not permitted on ..."

ERROR Screenshot: